# how can i page into my list using linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, paging

i have a linq query to get data from a database.  something like:

```
Repository.Query<Project>.Where(r=>r.IsActive).OrderBy(r=>r.Date);
```

i then return this to a viewmodel.  i now want to add paging so i get an additional parameter in my controller action which is the page so i want something to add to my query to return lets say 10 results * the page number:

So if its page 1, i want to get the first 10 results. I know i can use the

```
.Take(10)
```

to do this but i am unsure how to do this when the page passed in is 2 or 3 or anything but 1.

what is the best way (and most efficient) to do this ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a combination of [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357513.aspx) and [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx):

```
.Skip((page - 1) * resultsPerPage).Take(resultsPerPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an extension method. Chances are, you'll need this all over your web application.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakePage<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int page, int pageSize = 10) where T : class
{
    return items.Skip(pageSize * (page - 1)).Take(pageSize);
}
```

Usage:

```
int page = 2;
int pageSize = 25;
Repository.Query<Project>.Where(r=>r.IsActive).TakePage(page, pageSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this: `.Skip((page ?? 0) * resultsPerPage).Take(resultsPerPage);`